# Flutter - Rows with Icons like a Bow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, font-awesome

in my form I have a Container with some Rows and nested Icons. Every Icon has got a Tap event with a function.

How can I curve all Rows with Icons like this.

[image: Rows and Icons]

to obtain this result as a bow (like rainbow)?

[image: Curved Rows with Icons]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no shortcut to do this if you want a smooth curve. You must provide some constrains that what the ratio of width and height and calculate the curve formulation. You can try to combine **Stack** & **Align** to fullfill your layout.

Here is my assumption from your image:

- X axis is separated equally.
- Y axis is like a circular sector which radian from 1.25 pi to 1.75 pi  (a circle is 2 pi). So the total radian is pi

  ```
  import 'dart:math';

  class CustomRainbow extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      List<Widget> icons = List<Icon>.filled(14, Icon(Icons.tag_faces));

      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 130,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                ..._bridge(icons),
                ..._bridge(icons, row: 1),
                ..._bridge(icons, row: 2),
                ..._bridge(icons, row: 3),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    List<Widget> _bridge(List<Widget> icons, {int row = 0}) {

      double totalRad = pi;
      double rowHeightFactor = 0.4;

      int count = icons.length;
      double width = 2.0 / (count - 1);
      double singleRad = totalRad / (count + 1);
      double startRad = pi * 1.5 - totalRad * 0.5;

      List<Widget> result = [];

      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result.add(
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(
                  -1 + i * width, sin((startRad + singleRad * (i + 1)))) +
                Alignment(0, row * rowHeightFactor),
            child: icons[i],
          ),
        );
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
  ```

You can still tune the **Width**, **Height**, **totalRad** and **rowHeightFactor**,
Make sure the Alignment value is in range of (-1.0, 1.0) and all the icons will be in the Container.

Answer (score 0):

A hack could be to display row(column) and to add a transparent (default) container with the respective height for each column as the first element, to move the subsequent icons downwards.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing that is to build Columns inside the Row with placeholders that will ocuppy some bottom space to make taller columns:

```
static const double size = 40.0;
static const placeholderSize = size / 2;
static const int columnsNumber = 8;

Widget repeatedWidget() {
  return IconButton(
    icon: Icon(         //Your icon button
      Icons.tag_faces,
      size: size,
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: List.generate(     //generating a fixed number of columns with icons for the example
        columnsNumber,
        (index) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: List.generate(
              6,
              (index) => repeatedWidget(),
            )..add(         //adding a widget at the final of each Column
                Column(
                  children: List.generate(

                    /*if the current index is greater or equal to half of the number 
                    of columns return it minus index - 1, else return the index*/
                    index >= columnsNumber / 2
                        ? columnsNumber - index - 1
                        : index,
                    (index) => Container( //containers that will ocuppy the bottom space of each column
                      height: placeholderSize,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The result:

[image]